# Understanding prototype Property of function

Tags: javascript, prototype

Taken an example if

```
var Func = function(){}
```

Here Func has property called prototype and I can add my custom methods like the following.

```
Func.prototype.move = function(){ //do something }
```

As per my understanding here prototype is just another property of Func which is by default provided by the interpreter and is not used to delegate any functionality, ie. there is nothing like

```
Func.move()
```

Applying the same logic I am creating another property of the same function like the following

```
Func.method = function(){ //do something }
```

Now if a create a new object

```
var obj = new Func();
```

Here there is `obj.move()` but `obj.method()` wont be there. If prototype is just another property with no magical advantages then why this certain behavior ?? Thanks in advance !

Comment: You are incorrect. A function's `prototype` property *is* magical.

Comment: `prototype` property is used to lookup the property/function in `prototype chain`. So when you ask a `property` of any `object` first its looked up on that `object` itself, if not found then its been searched through the `object`'s `prototypical chain` upto `Object`. So particular to your example, you are adding `method` property directly on the `Func` object so it would be available only on that instance in this case on `Func` & you are adding the `move` property to the prototype of `Func`, so it would be made available through the `prototypical chain lookup`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `new` the `prototype` property of the function will be used as a template for the internal `[[Prototype]]` property of the instance object. This is exposed in some browsers as `__proto__`, not to confuse with `prototype` which again, it is just a regular property.

When you attach a property to the function directly, as opposed to the `prototype`, you are basically using the function as a namespace. Since functions are objects, they can have arbitrary properties, and others are built-in, like `prototype` and `name` for example. In effect you are creating something similar to a static method, one that doesn't depend on the instance, that doesn't use `this`.

Answer (score 4):

The prototype property of a function does have a special purpose: it will be set as the internal prototype of objects created by using this function as a constructor function (ie. when you use `new`).

So when you write `var obj = new Func();` obj doesn't have an *own* property `move`, but when the lookup fails, it gets delegated upwards the prototype chain: to the prototype of `obj`, which is the Func.prototype you set earlier, which does have a move method.

On the other hand, adding move to Func is just creating a property of the function itself *(functions are objects too, so you can add properties to them)* - you can call it with `Func.move()`, but it will have basically nothing to do with `obj`.

If you want to read up more about how a function's prototype *property* works, I recommend Eloquent Javascript's chapter [The Secret Life of Objects](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html).

Answer (score 1):

With move, you are adding the function to the object's prototype, thus it is available to newly created objects.
With method, you are adding the function to the *already created* object Func.

Answer (score 1):

`prototype` property is used to lookup the property/function in `prototype chain`. So when you ask a `property` of any `object` first its looked up on that `object` itself, if not found then its been searched through the `object`'s `prototypical chain` upto `Object`. So particular to your example, you are adding `method` property directly on the `Func` object so it would be available only on that instance in this case on `Func` & you are adding the `move` property to the prototype of `Func`, so it would be made available through the `prototypical chain lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should explain the difference:

```js
Func = function(){};

Func.prototype.move = function(){ 
    alert('move');
}

Func.method = function(){ 
    alert('method');
};

var obj = new Func();
//valid since move is defined using prototype and hence available on all instances of Func
obj.move(); 
//valid since you just added a method to Func and invoking it directly using Func
Func.method();

//invalid since method was not defined using prototype
obj.method();
//invalid since move was not defined using prototype and hence available only on instances of Func and not as a property of Func
Func.move();
```